# How to get a BigDecimal from a HashMap<String,Object> in Drools 5.4.0

Tags: java, drools

I use a Map to put the conditions.
My Object To:

```
public class TestTO implements Serializable {

private String resultStr;

private List resultList;

private Map resultMap;

private Map parameterMap;
... ...
}
```

Execute Drools Rule:

```
public static Map getMapResult(TestTO rulesTo) throws Exception {
    StatelessKnowledgeSession kSession = getKnowledgeSession();
    AgendaEventListener ael = mock( AgendaEventListener.class );
    kSession.addEventListener(ael);
    kSession.execute(rulesTo);
    Map resultMap = rulesTo.getResultMap();
    if (resultMap != null && !resultMap.isEmpty())
        return resultMap;
    else throw new RuntimeException("EMPTY");
}
```

My test method:

```
public void TestA() throws Exception{
Map<String, Object> test= new HashMap<String, Object>();
test.put("str1", "0");//string
test.put("str2", "SC");//string
test.put("dec1", new BigDecimal(372));//bigdecimal
TestTO m = new TestTo();
m.setParameterMap(test);
for(int i=0;i<22;i++){
    m.setResultMap(new HashMap<String, Object>());
    Map result=RuleTest.getMapResult(m);
  }
}
```

now I have a problem about the rules file, how to get `"dec1"` from the `parameterMap`,because this map's value are `Object ,if we get the value from this map by key. it's ok. but how to convert the value from`object`to`bigdecimal`? I try to get value in drl file using two ways:

1.`to.getParameterMap()["gt"]>=300`. but it has some problems.

2.`to.getParameterMap()["gt"]>=300B`. maybe it is ok.

why the second is ok (I think)?.

I do not have to specify a default value for drools dialect. So I think default is "java".

Does java dialect support `300B`?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you now that every Object in there is a BigDecimal, why not just cast it? Another way can be to ask if it's a BigDecimal with Object.getClass()

Comment: not every object ,just 1-3 are BigDecimal.i just want to know 300B is correct or incorrect . @LeoPflug

Comment: Since I don't know it, probably not. if you want to check if a BigInteger is greater you have to use the methods of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `Entry` with key "dec1" is always a BigDecimal:

```
Entry(key == "dec1", $val : value) from myMap.entrySet()
$bigD : BigDecimal() from $val
```

I think that's right ... it compiles for me, but I'm feeling lazy, so I haven't written a test to prove it.

Comment: sorry,how to write it using excel file.